# How to add property bag javascript

Tags: sandbox-solution

how can I add a property let say "StartDate" to the subweb i just created in this code,

```
var clientContext;
var website;
var subweb;

SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', sharePointReady);

function sharePointReady() {
    clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    website = clientContext.get_web();
    clientContext.load(website);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSucceeded, onRequestFailed);
}
function onRequestSucceeded() {
    var WCI = new SP.WebCreationInformation();
    WCI.set_webTemplate('STS#0');
    WCI.set_description('abc6');
    WCI.set_title('abc6');
    WCI.set_url("abc6");
    WCI.set_language(1033);

    subweb = website.get_webs().add(WCI);
    website.update();
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSucceeded2, onRequestFailed);
}
function onRequestSucceeded2() {
    alert("done!");
}
function onRequestFailed() {
    alert("Failed");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Making use of the Property Bag in the ECMAScript Client Object Model](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/pages/making-use-of-the-property-bag-in-the-ecmascript-client-object-model.aspx)

```
function getWebProperty() {
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = ctx.get_site().get_rootweb();
    this.props =  web.get_allProperties();
    this.props.set_item("aProperty", "aValue");
    ctx.load(web);

    ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, gotProperty), Function.createDelegate(this, failedGettingProperty));
}

function gotProperty() {
    alert(this.props.get_item("aProperty"));
}

function failedGettingProperty() {
    alert("failed");
}
```

Comment: any way to make these values indexable (particularly in SharePoint Online)?

Comment: You mean so you can search on them?

Comment: Yes, i've used similar code before to inject properties into a web's property bag, but they don't get crawled in SharePoint Online.

Comment: The properties are meant to be used for configuration type information and are never surfaced to the UI. I'm pretty sure you can't get search to crawl them.

Comment: you are missing **`web.udpdate()`** add the property permanent

Comment: You can crawl them, but it takes some secret sauce: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2013/10/12/ftc-to-cam-setting-indexed-property-bag-keys-using-csom.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I am adding a function to get property bag value and update setWebProperty function.

**Set PropetyBag Value**

```
function setWebProperty() {
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_site().get_rootweb();
this.props =  web.get_allProperties();
this.props.set_item(“aProperty”, “aValue”);
ctx.load(web);
web.update();
ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, setProperty),  Function.createDelegate(this, failedGettingProperty));
}

function setProperty() {
 alert(this.props.get_item(“aProperty”));
}

function failedGettingProperty() {
  alert("failed");
}
```

**Get PropertyBagValue**

```
function getWebProperty() {
   var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = ctx.get_site().get_rootweb();
   this.props =  web.get_allProperties();
   ctx.load(this.props);
   ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, gotProperty), Function.createDelegate(this, failedGettingProperty));
}
function gotProperty() {
   alert(props.get_fieldValues()["aProperty"]);
}
function failedGettingProperty() {
  alert("failed");
}
```